# How to setup an account of VSTS(corporate) with an account of Azure(personal) to Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

I have an account which is bound to VSTS that is corporative, and an Azure account that is bound to the same email but as a personal account.

- VSTS Account: jonathan@company.com(Corporative account)
- Azure Account: jonathan@company.com(Personal account).

I have a Build Definition which generates a package.zip of my Web App. I can't use Release of VSTS to get this package.zip and publish it, because i can't create an Azure Resource Manager with my Azure Subscription, because my Azure account is a Microsoft Personal Account and my VSTS Account is a Microsoft Corporative Account. I tryed to use TenantId but VSTS don`t let me create this Service Endpoint.

Image of VSTS Services Endpoints.
[image: Image of VSTS Services Endpoints]

Image of VSTS Release. If i can create a Service Endpoint(Azure RM) with the Azure Subscription of my Personal Account, the Subscription will appear in AzureRM Subscription drop down. 
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you say you have a build which generates artifacts. You want to use these artifacts in your release of VSTS? What do your accounts have to do with this? Where do you want to deploy to? Azure?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited the question by improving the formatting and adding new information to make it clearer.

Yes! I have a Build which generates artifacts and i want to use Release to publish that artifact. But i can't link the Subscrition of Personal Account to a VSTS Corporative Account to create a Service Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using your own identity to create an ARM Endpoint. You should create a service principal in Azure and after that create an ARM Endpoint in VSTS with Service Principal information.

You can read how to do this in my blogpost [here](https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2016/07/27/create-an-azure-service-principal-and-a-vsts-arm-endpoint/).